# Console application with Java and gradle

Tags: java, console-application, gradle

I am writing a console application with Java and gradle. I am using the [`application` plugin](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/application_plugin.html) and have the required fields correctly configured in `build.gradle`.

In my main class I have `BufferedReader` linked with `System.in`. Here's the problem: When I run `gradle run` in project directory, the reader does not wait for my console input. `BufferedReader#readLine` instead returns `null` on the very first call. This behavior is not desirable for what am I doing.

What is the solution? Is there a separate console application plugin for gradle or do I need to tweak `application` plugin somehow to suit my needs?

Comment: 4 years later! If you are running a Windows OS, I have just found that by running the task from a Cygwin terminal this annoying "> Building ..." stuff does not appear. But I've also found that putting `standardInput = System.in` only works for me if I put it inside a specially defined `task`, not when inside `run`.

Comment: I'd consider this a defect in Gradle.

Comment: Related Gradle issues: https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/1251 and https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/2842

Answer (score 119, accepted):

By default, the *system.in* of your Gradle build is not wired up with the *system.in* of the *run* (JavaExec) task. You can do the following:

build.gradle (Groovy syntax):

```
run {
    standardInput = System.in
}
```

build.gradle.kts ([Kotlin DSL](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/kotlin_dsl.html) syntax):

```kotlin
tasks.named<JavaExec>("run") {
    standardInput = System.`in`
}
```

Comment: Thank you! That was a great help. Now is there a way to avoid printing `> Building > :run` when it prompts user for next input?

Comment: unfortunately not at the moment. I've raised an issue for that a while ago: http://issues.gradle.org/browse/GRADLE-1147 you can vote for it.

Comment: Thank you, again. This too will do. Accepting your answer. :)

Comment: I tried the same exact thing but Gradle gets stuck and no input gets printed to command line if I type. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I have a [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22567831/gradle-execute-groovy-interactive-shell-with-project-classpath) for that.

Comment: If using the Kotlin dsl you need to escape the `in` since it is a keyword in Kotlin. Use backticks like so: ``standardInput = System.`in` ``

Comment: Use `--console=plain` so nothing gets printed after asking for input

Answer (score 39):

As stated above, add

```
run {
   standardInput = System.in
}
```

And run:

```
gradle console:run -q --console=plain
```

where:

- `-q` runs task in "quiet" mode (to avoid having `> Building > :run`)
- `--console=plain` drops execution status: `<=-> 80% EXECUTING [TIME]`

Source: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_command_line.html

Comment: this execution status spoils output when I want to use carriage return (it duplicates on each line). do you know how to disable it without --console=plain because it also disables carriage return processing

Answer (score 5):

For `build.gradle.kts`:

```
tasks.getByName<JavaExec>("run") {
    standardInput = System.`in`
}
```

Comment: I've also found that you can do `(tasks.run) { standardInput = /* ... */ }`

Answer (score -4):

Chances are, the problem lies in your java code. All the application plugin does is compile the java code, and run the main class that you specify. Can you post the code in your main class that you specified for the application plugin (mainClassName) ?

Comment: I ran the code from within IntelliJ IDEA as well. (By right-clicking the file and selecting `Run <classname>.main`.) It works just fine there.