# Gradle Java Console Application

Tags: java, command-line, gradle

I am writing a console application with Java and gradle. In my java application i am trying to accept input from the user. It is working without any issue if i run via eclipse IDE. But if i run from command line it is not stopping to accept user input. Here is the build.gradle file.  [Here is link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13172137/console-application-with-java-and-gradle) which says to add

```
run {
 standardInput = System.in
}
```

but still i could not succeed.

```
sourceSets {
    generated {
        java {
           srcDir 'src/generated/java'
        }
        resources {
           srcDir 'src/generated/resources'
        }
    }
    main {
        compileClasspath += sourceSets.generated.runtimeClasspath
    }
    test {
        compileClasspath += sourceSets.generated.runtimeClasspath               
        //System.setProperty('easy', 'false')       

    }
    run {
        standardInput = System.in
    }
}
```

Comment: Gradle is just tool for building app. Why do you want to input from user during build? Is it some parametr for building?

Answer (score 0):

IF you want to customize your build process, use property via *-PnameOfProperty=xxx* (recommendation from gradle, instead of *-D* for java property)