# java.util.scanner throws NoSuchElementException when application is started with gradle run

Tags: java, gradle, java.util.scanner, build.gradle, stdin

I have a created a simple java "echo" application that takes a user's input and shows it back to them to demonstrate the issue. I can run this application without trouble using IntelliJ's internal "run" command, and also when executing the compiled java file produced by `gradle build`. However, if I try to execute the application using `gradle run`, I get a NoSuchElementException thrown from the scanner.

I think gradle or the application plugin specifically is doing something strange with the system IO.

**Application**

```
package org.gradle.example.simple;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class HelloWorld {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String response = input.nextLine();
    System.out.println(response);
  }
}
```

**build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'java'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

apply plugin: 'java'

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'org.gradle.example.simple.HelloWorld'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'application'

mainClassName = "org.gradle.example.simple.HelloWorld"

sourceCompatibility = 1.5

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
}
```

Any ideas how to make this application work using `gradle run`?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You must wire up default stdin to gradle, put this in build.gradle:

```
run {
    standardInput = System.in
}
```

**UPDATE: 9 Sep 2021**

As suggested by `nickbdyer` in the comments run `gradlew run` with `--console plain` option to avoid all those noisy and irritating prompts

Example

```
gradlew --console plain run
```

And if you also want to completely get rid of all gradle tasks logs add `-q` option

Example

```
gradlew -q --console plain run
```

Comment: This works great, and for anyone that is annoyed by the ugly prompt that now appears `gradle --console plain run` removes it. There is an open issue https://issues.gradle.org/browse/GRADLE-1147 for this, where I found that snippet.

Comment: If not using the application plugin, the `standardInput = System.in` line should go within whatever task you are running that needs stdin redirected to it. For me it was within a custom [JavaExec](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.JavaExec.html) task.

Comment: Dude it doesn't work in my run script. Can you explain more?

Comment: You just put that snippet in build.gradle and type gradle run, whats the error you got ?

Comment: Could not find method run() for arguments [build_70djsz9uqda5dtwfrqrhv32tu$_run_closure3@446452bb] on root project <projectname> of type org.gradle.api.Project.

Comment: @AlirezaMohamadi make sure you have `id 'application'` in your build.gradle `plugins { }` block

Answer (score 3):

I'm learning to use [Gradle with Kotlin DSL](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/kotlin_dsl.html) and what worked for me was answered [here before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13172566/13556596).

```
// build.gradle (Groovy syntax)
run {
    standardInput = System.in
}

// build.gradle.kts (Kotlin syntax)
tasks.named<JavaExec>("run") {
    standardInput = System.`in`
}
```

The solution provided by @MarkusWeninger didn't worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the accepted answer: If you who are using the [*Gradle Kotlin DSL*](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/kotlin_dsl.html) instead of the normal Groovy DSL, you have to write the following:

```
tasks {
    run {
        standardInput = System.`in`
    }
}
```

---

Additional note: I had a similar problem in a Spring Boot application. There, I had to modify the `bootRun` task instead of the `run` task.