# Can't run the Java project in NetBeans

Tags: java, gradle, exception, nosuchelementexception

When I try to run my java project in NetBeans with a Scanner in it, it doesn't run and shows error message in the output field.
"FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.(Scanner). processResources NO-SOURCE".

When I delete `names[x] = s.next();` and `grades[x] = s.nextInt();` it runs.
I looked for a solution a lot but non of them have worked for me.
Note that I can run the same code in Android Studio.
I'm a beginner in programming, anyone have an idea how to fix it??

My code:

```
package codePracticing;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        
        
        java.util.Scanner s = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);
        
        String names[] = new String[5];
        int grades[] = new int[5];
        
        for (int x = 0; x < names.length; x++){
            if (x != 3){
                System.out.println("Enter Name Of Student Number" + String.valueOf(x + 1) + ": ");
                names[x] = s.next();
                System.out.println("Enter Grade Of Student Number" + String.valueOf(x + 1) + ": ");
                grades[x] = s.nextInt();
            }
        }

        for (int x = 0; x < names.length; x++){
            if (x != 3){
                System.out.println("Student Number " + String.valueOf(x + 1) + " " + names[x] + " ; Grade: " + grades[x]);
            }
        }
```

The error message in the Output tab:

```
JAVA_HOME="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-16.0.2"
cd C:\Users\***\Documents\NetBeansProjects\codePracticing; .\gradlew.bat --configure-on-demand -x check run
Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
> Task :compileJava
> Task :processResources NO-SOURCE
> Task :classes

> Task :run FAILED
Enter Name Of Student Number1: 
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:937)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1478)
    at codePracticing.Main.main(Main.java:28)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':run'.
> Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-16.0.2\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 381ms
2 actionable tasks: 2 executed
```

Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

I tried to copy the code to a **"Java with Ant"** project (instead of "Java with Gradle") and it worked without problems.

> *File → New project → Java with Ant → Java Application*

Comment: So what is "Ant" and "Gradle", what's the difference between them & why can't I use the "Scanner" methods in the Gradle?

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem in this code if you run it on java/ant. but if you want to run it on gradle you should see this post.
[java.util.scanner throws NoSuchElementException when application is started with gradle run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36723447/java-util-scanner-throws-nosuchelementexception-when-application-is-started-with)

Comment: Thanks for helping and for the link.. it was useful.