# Can't get Gradle to use System.in

Tags: gradle, inputstream, blocking, system.in

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13172137/console-application-with-java-and-gradle) explains how to use `System.in` when running a task to run a specific class in a project.

But for me currently it's not working: although I have included the `application` plugin and the following lines in `build.gradle`:

```
mainClassName = "misc.StreamsExp"
run{ 
    standardInput = System.in 
}
task stream( type: JavaExec, dependsOn: assemble ){
    classpath sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
    main = "misc.StreamsExp"
}
```

the line with `readLine` in the app code below should be blocking but it's not:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader( System.in ));

String enteredLine = "";
while( enteredLine == null || ! enteredLine.equals( "q" )){
    System.out.println( "spuds");
    enteredLine = br.readLine();
}
```

... instead the thing just spins on forever:

> spuds
>   spuds
>   spuds
>   ...

NB I am on a Windows 10 OS, with Java 8.91.  I have tried both the Windows DOS console and Cygwin.
NB2 The same thing occurs when I run this `stream` task inside Eclipse (Gradle STS Eclipse plugin)... but not when I do `Run as --> Java application`: then the blocking occurs as expected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hah... one of those sits where you think you're gonna be stumped forever and you find the solution 2 mins after posting to SO! I'll leave it here for anyone else...

The answer is to put the line `standardInput =` in the task you're running, like so:

```
task stream( type: JavaExec, dependsOn: assemble ){
    standardInput = System.in
    classpath sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
    main = "misc.StreamsExp"
}
```

Strangely, the prompt "spuds" is followed in the Windows DOS terminal by

> > Building 88% > :stream

... which is a known "bug" referred to in the question I referenced.  In Cygwin this bug does not happen.

CAVEAT: this works in the Windows DOS terminal and the Cygwin terminal... it does **NOT** solve the problem when running the bespoke `stream` task in Eclipse!

Comment: Right ... as I said, in my case, it did not work in the Eclipse IDE.  It seems only to work in a CLI terminal.