# kotlin readLine not working with gradlew run

Tags: kotlin, gradle, build.gradle

I have a project I set up with gradle where I'm trying to read user input from the command line using `readLine()`. However when I run `./gradlew run` to run the project, it doesn't actually stop to wait for user input and exits the program after completing. Is it possible to read user input from the command line without having to pass them into arguments when starting the program?

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    readLine()
}
```

and here's my `build.gradle` just in case

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm' version '1.3.41'
    id 'application'
}

group 'project'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8"
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6'
}

compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
compileTestKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}

application {
    mainClass = 'MainKt'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`run { standardInput = System.in }`

refer to previous answer
[Console application with Java and gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13172137/console-application-with-java-and-gradle)